# Return a string made with a line read from input

Tags: c, string, pointers, input

i am trying to code a C **function which returns a line read from the input as a char*** . I am on Windows and i test my program in the command line by giving files as input and output of my program like this:

```
cl program.c
program < test_in.txt > test_out.txt
```

This is my (not working) function:

```
char* getLine(void)
{
    char* result = "";
    int i, c;

    i = 1;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
         *result++ = c;
         i++;

         if(c == '\n')
            return result - i;
    }

    return result - i;
}
```

I was expecting it to work because i previously wrote:

```
char* getString(char* string)
{

    //char* result = string; // the following code achieve this.
    char* result = "";
    int i;

    for(i = 1; *result++ = *string++; i++);

    return result - i;
}
```

And these lines of code have a correct behaviour.
Even if every answers will be appreciated, i would be really thankfull 
**if any of you could explain me why my getString() function works while my getLine() function doesn't**.

Comment: regarding this line in getline() `char* result = "";`, this is setting the pointer to some readonly literal.  Suggest using `char* result = NULL;`  this line: `*result++ = c;` will result in undefined behaviour and lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest call `realloc()` with parameters `result` and the current number of characters in the line before trying to set the new character into the allocated memory pointed to by result.   Be sure to actually allocate one more character than is actually needed, so in the end can append a NUL char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function does not allocate enough space for the string being read. The variable char* result = "" defines a char pointer to a string literal ("", empty string), and you store some arbitrary number of characters into the location pointed to by result.

```
char* getLine(void)
{
    char* result = ""; //you need space to store input
    int i, c;

    i = 1;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        *result++ = c; //you should check space
        i++;

        if(c == '\n')
            return result - i; //you should null-terminate
    }
    return result - i; //you should null-terminate
}
```

You need to allocate space for your string, which is challenging because you don't know how much space you are going to need a priori.  So you need to decide whether to limit how much you read (ala fgets), or dynamically reallocate space as you read more. Also, how to you indicate that you have finished input (reached EOF)?

The following alternative assumes dynamic reallocation is your chosen strategy.

```
char* getLine(void)
{
    int ch; int size=100; size_t pos=0;
    char* result = malloc(size*sizeof(char*));
    while( (ch=getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        *result++ = ch;
        if( ++pos >= size ) {
            realloc(result,size+=100);
            //or,realloc(result,size*=2);
            if(!result) exit(1); //realloc failed
        }
        if( c=='\n' ) break;
    }
    *result = '\0'; //null-terminate
    return result - pos;
}
```

*When you are done with the string returned from the above function, please remember to free() the allocated space.*

This alternative assumes you provide a buffer to store the string (and specifies the size of the buffer).

```
char* getLine(char* buffer, size_t size)
{
    int ch;
    char* result = buffer;
    size_t pos=0;
    while( (ch=getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        *result++ = ch;
        if( ++pos >= size ) break; //full
        if( c=='\n' ) break;
    }
    *result = '\0'; //null-terminate
    return buffer;
}
```

Both avoid the subtle interaction between detecting EOF, and having enough space to store a character read. The solution is to buffer a character if you read and there is not enough room, and then inject that on a subsequent read. You will also need to null-ter

Comment: Last `getlien()` has weaknesses.  `if( ++pos >= size ) return buffer;` --> `buffer` not null character terminated.  2 ) corner case `*result++` is a problem if `size == 0`.  3) `size_t pos=0`   Still a nice answer.

Comment: Agreed, I ignored size==0 (to keep the example/presentation simple); fixed the size_t pos=0 (used int since OP used int). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, i diddn't knew about malloc(). Does the line ` char* result = malloc(size*sizeof(char*)); ` ask for result to be stored in memory with the size of 100 char ? If yes, why 100 instead of just 1? Is it because it would be more costly to realloc(result, size+=1) at every new char added?

Comment: @ChuckCottrill By the way in the dynamic version i think you wrote result = '\0' instead of *result = '\0' .

Answer (score 3):

Both functions have [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) since you are modifying string literals. It just *seems* to work in one case. Basically, `result` needs to point to memory that can be legally accessed, which is not the case in either of the snippets.

On the same subject, you might find this useful: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: These articles seems very interesting, but i am still a begginer so i only understand half of these things and above all i can't link these informations to my issue. At least now i know the reason why my compiler let me doing "wrong" things with pointer and memory.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way. 
When you say

```
char* result = "";
```

you are setting up a pointer 'result' to point to a 1-byte null terminated string (just the null).  Since it is a local variable it will be allocated on the stack.

Then when you say

```
*result++ = c;
```

you are storing that value 'c' in to that address + 1.
So, where are you putting it?
Well, most stacks are to-down; so they grow toward lower addresses; so, you are probably writing over what is already on the stack (the return address for whatever called this, all the registers it needs restore and all sorts of important stuff).

That is why you have to be very careful with pointers.

Comment: I see. I must be really naive because i thought memory were automaticaly allocated  when you were incrementing a pointer... In my mind it was working like this: ` char* result = "";   /* result[0] = "" */   *result++ = c;    /* result[0] = c */  *result++ = c   /* result[1] = c */ `

Comment: wrong and wrong.  First, the pointer `result` is on the stack, the place where is points is in readonly memory (whereever the linker placed the "" literal.  Second, the `++` is performed after the assignment is performed, (and then the pointer to the start of the string is lost.)  Suggest 1) malloc memory to point toward 2) use a counter so the assignment is `result[counter] = newchar; counter++;`  where `counter` was initialized to 0

Comment: Good point on the post increment but, it will still have the same effect the next time around the loop.  Regarding the stack being readonly memory, that is compiler/processor dependent.  I have definitely seen people accidentally change literals and write into the stack.

Answer (score 1):

When you expect to return a string from a function, you have two options (1) provide a string to the function with adequate space to hold the string (including the null-terminating character), or (2) dynamically allocate memory for the string within the function and return a pointer. Within your function you must also have a way to insure your are not writing beyond the end of the space available *and* you are leaving room for the null-terminating character. That requires passing a maximum size if you are providing the array to the function, and keeping count of the characters read.

Putting that together, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 256

char* getLine (char *s, int max)
{
    int i = 0, c = 0;
    char *p = s;

    while (i + 1 < max && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        *p++ = c;
        i++;
    }
    *p = 0;
    return s;
}

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC] = {0};

    printf ("\ninput : ");
    getLine (buf, MAXC);

    printf ("output: %s\n\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example/Output**

```
$ ./bin/getLine

input : A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
output: A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```